# How to POST binary bytes using java async http client (ning) library

Tags: java, asynchronous, httpclient

I need to use Async Http Client (https://github.com/sonatype/async-http-client ) to post an byte array to URL.Content type is octet-stream.

How Do I do it using async http client.
Should I use ByteArrayBodyGenerator ? Is there any example code to see how it is done?

If the byte array is already in memory, is it better to use ByteArrayInputStream 
and use RequestBuilder.setBody(InputStream)

Answer (score 2):

It is suggested in the docs to not to use InputStream in `setBody`, because in order to get the content length, the library will need to load everything in memory.

And it seems that ByteArrayBodyGenerator has the same issue. To get the content length it uses a call to `bytes.length()` and `bytes` is your byte array (private final byte[] bytes;). So, to get the length of a byte array, the array needs to be loaded in memory.

Here is the source from github: 
https://github.com/sonatype/async-http-client/blob/master/src/main/java/com/ning/http/client/generators/ByteArrayBodyGenerator.java

You may write your own BodyGenerator implementation to avoid the issue.

Also you asked for an example of using BodyGenerator:

```
final SimpleAsyncHttpClient client = new SimpleAsyncHttpClient.Builder()
                .setRequestTimeoutInMs(Integer.MAX_VALUE)
                .setUrl(url)
                .build();

client.post(new ByteArrayBodyGenerator(YOUR_BYTE_ARRAY)).get();
```

And if you want to use legacy API:

```
final AsyncHttpClientConfig config
     = new AsyncHttpClientConfig.Builder().setRequestTimeoutInMs(Integer.MAX_VALUE).build();

final AsyncHttpClient client = new AsyncHttpClient(config);

client.preparePost(url)
        .setBody(new ByteArrayBodyGenerator(YOUR_BYTE_ARRAY))
        .execute()
        .get();
```